# Unlimited storage on Google Drive for students

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, online-storage

Context: http://googleforeducation.blogspot.in/2014/09/announcing-drive-for-education-21st.html

1. Can any student with a `.edu` email address get unlimited storage in Google Drive just by signing up?
2. Is [this](https://www.google.com/a/signup/u/0/?enterprise_product=GOOGLE.EDU#0) the correct website for signing up for students?
3. How time is required after signing up by students, before getting unlimited storage? Is it instant?

Comment: Fact which I later discovered: If your .edu account is provided by Microsoft/Hotmail/Outlook/Live, you would have probably got a terabyte of storage on OneDrive already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unlimited Drive storage is offered as a part of [Google Apps for Education](https://www.google.com/edu/). This is not something an individual student can obtain; rather, school officials enters an agreement with Google on behalf of the school. After that, all students have access to unlimited Drive, etc. All that a student can do is to encourage their school officials to do this.

So, the answers to your questions are:

1. No, students do not get unlimited storage if acting as individuals.
2. No, this is a form for a school official who will administer Google Apps for their school.
3. Not applicable, since students do not sign up by themselves. There is probably some substantial time between filling out the form in 2 and domain creation (since someone from Google will need to contact the school officials and create a formal agreement). After the Apps domain is created, students get unlimited storage as soon as they create accounts on that domain.